# populating excel with texboxes

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel

I am trying to create a small userform call log.
The user takes details and on button click, the specified excel sheet will be populated with the text boxes.
I'm relatively new to VBA and cannot seem to populate columns on the current row (which should be empty) with the specified text boxes (e.g. column A = tb1.text, column b = tb2.text)
I have the "find empty row" working properly.
I have deleted the failed attempts at properly populating columns but need to keep the same format as this is being written in Visual Studio.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_submit.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\_Private Data - NO BACKUP\Test OM Sheet.xlsx")
    objWorksheet = CType(objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim emptyrow As Integer = lastrow + 0,1
    objWorksheet.Cells(emptyrow, 0) = tb_date_time.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 1) = tb_user_name.Text

    objWorksheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1) = tb_date_time.Text
    objWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    objWorkbook.Save()
    objWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    objWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\_Private Data - NO BACKUP\Test OM Sheet Backup.xlsx")
    objWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    objExcel.Quit()


    Call reset_form()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have the "find empty row" working properly

Actually, I think that is where your issue is. This code:

```
Dim lastrow As Integer = objWorksheet.Cells.Rows.Count
Dim emptyrow As Integer = lastrow + 1
```

Will return 1 + the last possible row in the spreadsheet, which will through an error in

```
objWorksheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1) = tb_date_time.Text
```

because it will look for a cell row number that does not exist.

Try this instead.

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row + 1
Dim emptyrow As Integer = lastrow + 1
objWorksheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1) = tb_date_time.Text
```

I am not well versed in VSTO, so my syntax may be a bit off, but conceptually that should work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this. It's messy trying to do this on my own so I appreciate the help

Comment: Well this keeps telling me xlUp is not declared, looking into that too. EDIT: Got that part {Excel.XlDirection.xlUp}

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really messy but this is what I ended up with. I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I have moved on to the next part of the code.

```
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 1) = tb_date_time.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 2) = tb_user_name.Text
    If rb_bs.Checked = True Then
        objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 3) = rb_bs.Text
    ElseIf rb_wm.Checked = True Then
        objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 3) = rb_wm.Text
    ElseIf rb_gw.Checked = True Then
        objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 3) = rb_gw.Text
    End If
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 4) = tb_caller_name.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 5) = cb_company.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 6) = cb_transfer.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 7) = tb_call_notes.Text
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 8) = tb_solution.Text
    If chkb_resolved.Checked = True Then
        objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 9) = chkb_resolved.Text
    Else
        objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 9) = Text("")
    End If
    objWorksheet.Cells(lastrow, 10) = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```